# Using wildcard to do queryset filter in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have three columns (var1, va2 and var3) in my database.

On the html page, a user can input values for var1, var2, or var3 or a combination of the three variables (e.g. provide data only for var1 and var3, or var2 and var3).

My query search is:

```
Rule.objects.filter(var1=user_var1, var2=user_var2, var3=user_var3, )
```

If the user enters values for all three variables, this is pretty straight forward.

If the user enter values for two or one of the variables, I would like the queryset filter to match only the columns that the users entered values for. For example: users entered data for var2 and var3. The resulting search would be:

```
Rule.objects.filter(var2=user_var2, var3=user_var3, )
```

But is there a way to keep all three variable in the filter code and so something like:

```
if user_var1 = null, then user_var1=[wildcard or all]

Rule.objects.filter(var1=user_var1, var2=user_var2, var3=user_var3, )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be or like previous answer

```
filter_vars = ['vars1', 'vars2', 'vars3']
filter_dic = {}
for item in filter_vars:
    user_var = request.GET.get(item, '')
    if user_var:
       filter_dic[item] = user_var
Rule.objects.filter(**filter_dic)
```

Answer (score 2):

Prepare a dict of filters to be applied if values provided otherwise return all queryset:

```
filters = {}
if user_var1:
    filters['var1'] = user_var1
if user_var2:
    filters['var2'] = user_var2
qs = Rule.objects.filter(**filters)
```

Comment: Why do you do a qs first and then filter. Why not just filter it through the dict directly?

Comment: @HC you can, i was just trying to be more explainatory. See updated code. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I thought may be it make the code run faster. Thanks!